# iPhone like checkbox cocoa (mac) control

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am looking for an control which mimics the iPhone checkbox on cocoa. Do you know is something like this already exists?

Comment: I take it you never bothered to spend 2 minutes looking in IB…

Answer (score 3):

Mac OS X has a check box control.  It's an `NSButton` with a button of type `NSSwitchButton`.

Comment: It would be nice if the OP would accept this as the right answer.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, I am looking for soemthing havin the look and feel of an UISwitch but for a mac app, not just a regular checkbox.

Comment: @AP: No you are not.  Generally people use a mouse with a Macintosh which means that swipe gestures are not as natural as with iOS.  If you try to make your Mac app behave like an iOS app it will be disastrous.

Comment: @AP: Further to my last comment, I have found out that Microsoft Word 2011 has a check box that looks like a slider switch.  It works like a toggle button with animation, but it looks like you have to swipe it to change its state (you don't) but it's an awkward control anyway.